# AbstractCouchbaseDataConfiguration.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I m using

org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.6.RELEASE'
spring-data-couchbase', version: '4.0.5.RELEASE'

Getting this error

2020-12-09 00:13:39.247  WARN 6802 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractCouchbaseDataConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2020-12-09 00:13:39.251 ERROR 6802 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2f490758: startup date [Wed Dec 09 00:13:38 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

2020-12-09 00:13:39.257  INFO 6802 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-09 00:13:39.261 ERROR 6802 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractCouchbaseDataConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:299) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/couchbase/config/AbstractCouchbaseDataConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:693) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted

@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

```
@Override
public String getConnectionString() {
    return "couchbase://127.0.0.1";
}

@Override
public String getUserName() {
    return "Administrator";
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return "password";
}

@Override
public String getBucketName() {
    return "travel-sample";
}
```

}

Comment: is there any way we can avoid error having same versions mentioned above

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this `spring-data-couchbase 4.X.X` does not work with `org.springframework.boot` `<2.3.X.RELEASE`. Updating your spring boot version to >`2.3.X.RELEASE` will solve this issue. Pom.xml snippets:

```
...
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
```

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <!-- -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
            <!-- -->
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```